# Sortable doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I have a problem. I would like to be able to sort the list. I made this script, but "sortable" doesn't work. Why?

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var count = 1;
        $(function(){
            $('#add_item').click(function(){
                count++;
                $('#container').append('<li id="item_' + count +'">' + count + '° posto: '+ '<input type="text" id="item_' + count + '" name="items[]" type="text" /><input type="submit" class="del_item" value="Elimina" /><br /></li>');
                return false;
            });
            $('form').on('click', '.del_item', function(){
                count--;
                $(this).parent().remove();
                return false;
            });
            $('#container').sortable();
        });
    </script>


<ul id="container">
            <li id="item_1">1° posto: <input type="text" id="item_1" name="items[]" />
            <input type="submit" class="del_item" value="Elimina" /><br /></li>
        </ul>
        <input type="submit" name="add_item" id="add_item" value="Aggiungi" /><br />

</html>
```

Could you help me, please?

Comment: Using the console in Chrome developer tools or Firefox with FireBug should give you some more information about the actual error

Comment: There is no `form` on your html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the above code, you haven't included the jquery and jquery-ui libraries. For example, put the following in the `<head>` section of your page:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also, you should add `<head>` and `<body>` tags around the appropriate content, so your page would look more like this:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var count = 1;
        $(function(){
            $('#add_item').click(function(){
                count++;
                $('#container').append('<li id="item_' + count +'">' + count + '° posto: '+ '<input type="text" id="item_' + count + '" name="items[]" type="text" /><input type="submit" class="del_item" value="Elimina" /><br /></li>');
                return false;
            });
            $('form').on('click', '.del_item', function(){
                count--;
                $(this).parent().remove();
                return false;
            });
            $('#container').sortable();
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>   
    <ul id="container">
        <li id="item_1">1° posto: <input type="text" id="item_1" name="items[]" />
        <input type="submit" class="del_item" value="Elimina" /><br /></li>
    </ul>
    <input type="submit" name="add_item" id="add_item" value="Aggiungi" /><br />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! Everything is correct in my script, except I missed the jquery-ui.min.js

Answer (score 0):

More precisely, you haven't included the jQueryUI library.
http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jqueryUI

So include both jQuery and jQueryUI

See this demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/pratik136/8JxfK/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've included the jquery and jquery-ui javascript files...

Check your JavaScript debugger, you have an error with the $('form').on('click'... line.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#add_item').click(function () {
            count = $('.del_item').length + 1;
            $('#container').append('<li id="item_' + count + '">' + count + '° posto: ' + '<input type="text" id="item_' + count + '" name="items[]" type="text" /><input type="button" class="del_item" value="Elimina" /><br /></li>');
            $('.del_item').click(function () {
                $(this).parent().remove();
                return false;
            });
            return false;
        });
        $('#container').sortable();
        $('#add_item').click();
    });
</script>

<ul id="container">
</ul>
<input type="button" name="add_item" id="add_item" value="Aggiungi" /><br />
```